# Deploy external file in c# solution with clickonce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I've a problem with Visual Studio Express 2010 c# edition.
I've a project that reference a DLL. This DLL has an external Excel file marked as
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always

When I build the solution, this Excel file is correctly copied into BIN\release solution folder.

BUT if I try to deploy the same solution, with Publish wizard, the Excel file is not copied in the install directory.

Please, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you saying that the Excel file is referenced only by the dll you are including in your project? That is a secondary reference, and ClickOnce will not see it and automatically include the file.

First, on your dll, I'm assuming it is referenced directly by your project. If so, then be sure you have added it to your project and set the Build Action to "none" and "copy to output directory" to "do not copy". Then delete your reference to it and re-add it, pointing it to the version now included in your project. Set the "copy local" property to "true". This will ensure the dll itself gets deployed correctly.

For the Excel file, you are going to have to add it to your project. Set the build action to "content" and set "copy to output directory" as "copy always". It will not be included automatically because it is a secondary reference to the ClickOnce app, not a direct/primary reference like the dll is.

Answer (score 9):

Open the **Publish properties** for your **ClickOnce** project. Then click on the **'Application Files ...'** button. That launches a dialog where you can control which files are being included in the publishing package.

In order for your XLSX file (or any other non build file) to appear in that dialog you need to  mark is as **'Content' in the Build Action** of the properties window.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add a file not listed in this menu?

Comment: @stexcec, I've edited my response. Mark the file as 'Content' and it will show up.

Comment: @PhilippSchmid, what if this file is in another class library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this file into solution and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

Answer (score 0):

It appears your file is not listed in the "PublishFiles" list. Open the Projects Properties, go to "Publish" Tab, click on "Application Files" button, make sure you see the DLL file in the list of files with Publish Status as "Include".

Comment: Thanks, in the "Application Files" window the referenced DLL is listed correctly with "Publish Status" set "Include". But no idea how to include in this menu also the external Excel File...

Comment: You may want to add the Excel file as well into your project, set its Build Action and Properties like how you did for the DLL file (Copy to Output Directory and Copy if newer or always, depending on your choice).

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the problem by inserting the Excel file as a resource, then writing it out like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(DestinationFileName, Properties.Resources.MyResourceFile);
```

I'm making an assumption that the Excel file is some kind of template you are using to build an output file from.